# Mail Sending Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I Have Big-Rock server on Linux Hosting, and server provides : Host and Port but  Magento default smtp provides windows server setting. so that's why magento not able to send mail ??

Comment: check your servers mail settings and log

Comment: log error: exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail'

Comment: I am write host:mail.domain.com and host:25

Comment: and also copy `app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Email/Template.php.` this file and paste in local folder. and change getMail function

Comment: `$my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
             $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
             $config = array(
                       'port' => $my_smtp_port,                                        
        'auth' => 'login',                   
                       'username' => 'user@domain.com', 
                       'password' => 'password'
        );
            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);`

Comment: change getMail function in this way

Comment: so can you help me out from this error